# How to count average from a certain range between two specific values?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, average

I have a list of data frames and would like to count average and sd from a certain range between two values. For example:

```
          t     value                                                         Z
0  27.21666  0.473294                                                      <NA>
1  27.31775  0.484845 {"type":"M","msg":"FIRST","time":27.2498,"dist":0.410454}
2  27.41881  0.457187                                                      <NA>
3  27.51916  0.429909                                                      <NA>
4  27.62018  0.401957                                                      <NA>
5  27.72040  0.373661                                                      <NA>
6  27.82057  0.346553                                                      <NA>
7  27.92117  0.319149                                                      <NA>
8  28.02310  0.291235                                                      <NA>
9  28.12421  0.264531                                                      <NA>
10 28.22576  0.237448                                                      <NA>
11 28.32797  0.210861                                                      <NA>
12 28.42993  0.183152                                                      <NA>
13 28.53069  0.156354                                                      <NA>
14 28.63218  0.128166                                                      <NA>
15 28.73285  0.100545                                                      <NA>
16 28.83326  0.072625                                                      <NA>
17 28.93670  0.042560                                                      <NA>
18 29.03824  0.012583                                                      <NA>
19 29.13856 -0.018004                                                      <NA>
20 29.23870 -0.049970                                                      <NA>
21 29.33917 -0.081763                                                      <NA>
22 29.44034 -0.113793                                                      <NA>
23 29.54193 -0.148269                                                      <NA>
24 29.64338 -0.182154                                                      <NA>
25 29.74523 -0.216842                                                      <NA>
26 29.84533 -0.252688                                                      <NA>
27 29.94582 -0.289105                                                      <NA>
28 30.04596 -0.325591                                                      <NA>
29 30.14973 -0.365179                                                      <NA>
30 30.24985 -0.403439                                                      <NA>
31 30.35072 -0.444497                                                      <NA>
32 30.45133 -0.485201                                                      <NA>
33 30.55292 -0.528480                                                      <NA>
34 30.65318 -0.572731                                                      <NA>
35 30.75435 -0.619512                                                      <NA>
36 30.85619 -0.667557                                                      <NA>
37 30.95747 -0.717658                                                      <NA>
38 31.06031 -0.769489                                                      <NA>
39 31.16094 -0.823372                                                      <NA>
40 31.26099 -0.876394 {"type":"M","msg":"LAST0","time":31.2458,"dist":0.521487}
41 31.36135 -0.932901                                                      <NA>
42 31.46322 -0.991948                                                      <NA>
43 31.56358 -1.049800                                                      <NA>
44 31.66395 -1.109068                                                      <NA>
45 31.76431 -1.166309                                                      <NA>
46 31.86441 -1.219613                                                      <NA>
47 31.96495 -1.266242                                                      <NA>
48 32.06650 -1.304891                                                      <NA>
49 32.16776 -1.331460                                                      <NA>
50 32.26796 -1.344302                                                      <NA>
```

I'd like to get the average and sd of the column "value" from all values between the start point (= the point in which the Z column has a value of "FIRST" included) and the endpoint (= the point in which the Z column has a value of "LAST0" included). How could I do this in R? Also, how could I just simply delete/filter out all the rows with "NA" before the value "FIRST" and after the value "LAST0" in the Z column?

As a bonus, how could I do this for all different instances if there were multiple similar sequences of values "FIRST" and "LAST0" introduced in one data frame..?

EDIT: Added a dput() below

```
> dput (tbl[[1]])
structure(list(t = c(27.216666, 27.317755, 27.418812, 27.519156, 27.620184, 
27.720402, 27.820574, 27.921171, 28.023102, 28.124214, 28.225763, 
28.327967, 28.429934, 28.530693, 28.632181, 28.732851, 28.83326, 
28.936697, 29.038239, 29.138559, 29.238697, 29.339165, 29.440336, 
29.541931, 29.643377, 29.745228, 29.845327, 29.945824, 30.045958, 
30.149729, 30.249853, 30.350716, 30.451326, 30.552917, 30.653179, 
30.754349, 30.856194, 30.957468, 31.06031, 31.16094, 31.260986, 
31.361355, 31.463219, 31.563583, 31.663948, 31.764309, 31.864408, 
31.964945, 32.066498, 32.167763, 32.267956, 32.368561, 32.469727, 
32.569916, 32.669949, 32.773418, 32.874977, 32.976883, 33.078552, 
33.181709, 33.282593, 33.385487, 33.486103, 33.588486, 33.690254, 
33.793388, 33.893703, 33.993759), value = c(0.473294, 0.484845, 0.457187, 
0.429909, 0.401957, 0.373661, 0.346553, 0.319149, 0.291235, 0.264531, 
0.237448, 0.210861, 0.183152, 0.156354, 0.128166, 0.100545, 0.072625, 
0.04256, 0.012583, -0.018004, -0.04997, -0.081763, -0.113793, 
-0.148269, -0.182154, -0.216842, -0.252688, -0.289105, -0.325591, 
-0.365179, -0.403439, -0.444497, -0.485201, -0.52848, -0.572731, 
-0.619512, -0.667557, -0.717658, -0.769489, -0.823372, -0.876394, 
-0.932901, -0.991948, -1.0498, -1.109068, -1.166309, -1.219613, 
-1.266242, -1.304891, -1.33146, -1.344302, -1.343445, -1.328416, 
-1.298611, -1.253834, -1.193182, -1.119025, -1.030697, -0.929913, 
-0.817493, -0.698029, -0.56889, -0.437583, -0.301298, -0.165372, 
-0.028239, 0.102254, 0.22927), Z = c(NA, "{\"type\":\"M\",\"msg\":\"FIRST\",\"time\":27.2498,\"dist\":0.410454}", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "{\"type\":\"M\",\"msg\":\"LAST0\",\"time\":31.2458,\"dist\":0.521487}", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-68L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this dataframe:

```r
          t     value           Z
0  27.21666  0.473294        <NA>
1  27.31775  0.484845 {msg:FIRST}
2  27.41881  0.457187        <NA>
3  27.51916  0.429909        <NA>
4  27.62018  0.401957        <NA>
5  27.72040  0.373661        <NA>
6  27.82057  0.346553        <NA>
7  27.92117  0.319149 {msg:LAST0}
32 30.45133 -0.485201        <NA>
33 30.55292 -0.528480        <NA>
34 30.65318 -0.572731        <NA>
35 30.75435 -0.619512        <NA>
36 30.85619 -0.667557 {msg:FIRST}
37 30.95747 -0.717658        <NA>
38 31.06031 -0.769489        <NA>
39 31.16094 -0.823372        <NA>
40 31.26099 -0.876394 {msg:LAST0}
41 31.36135 -0.932901        <NA>
50 32.26796 -1.344302        <NA>
```

With tidyverse functions, you can first use cumsum to identify groups between FIRST and LAST0, then filter out rows that are not between those two values, and then use mutate to compute the mean and sd.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(cum = cumsum(grepl("FIRST", Z) + lag(grepl("LAST0", Z), default = 0))) %>% 
  filter(cum %% 2 == 1) %>% 
  group_by(cum = as.numeric(as.factor(cum))) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value))

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   cum [2]
       t  value Z             cum   mean     sd
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  27.3  0.485 {msg:FIRST}     1  0.402 0.0598
 2  27.4  0.457 <NA>            1  0.402 0.0598
 3  27.5  0.430 <NA>            1  0.402 0.0598
 4  27.6  0.402 <NA>            1  0.402 0.0598
 5  27.7  0.374 <NA>            1  0.402 0.0598
 6  27.8  0.347 <NA>            1  0.402 0.0598
 7  27.9  0.319 {msg:LAST0}     1  0.402 0.0598
 8  30.9 -0.668 {msg:FIRST}     2 -0.771 0.0828
 9  31.0 -0.718 <NA>            2 -0.771 0.0828
10  31.1 -0.769 <NA>            2 -0.771 0.0828
11  31.2 -0.823 <NA>            2 -0.771 0.0828
12  31.3 -0.876 {msg:LAST0}     2 -0.771 0.0828
```

data

```r
structure(list(t = c(27.21666, 27.31775, 27.41881, 27.51916, 
27.62018, 27.7204, 27.82057, 27.92117, 30.45133, 30.55292, 30.65318, 
30.75435, 30.85619, 30.95747, 31.06031, 31.16094, 31.26099, 31.36135, 
32.26796), value = c(0.473294, 0.484845, 0.457187, 0.429909, 
0.401957, 0.373661, 0.346553, 0.319149, -0.485201, -0.52848, 
-0.572731, -0.619512, -0.667557, -0.717658, -0.769489, -0.823372, 
-0.876394, -0.932901, -1.344302), Z = c("<NA>", "{msg:FIRST}", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "{msg:LAST0}", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "{msg:FIRST}", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"{msg:LAST0}", "<NA>", "<NA>")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
"37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "50"))
```

Comment: Thank you!! Still would be cool to know tho, how could I just simply filter out all the rows after the value "LAST0" in the Z column? If I would want to get all the rows up to that point.

Comment: so, keeping everything but the last values after "LAST0"? You could do `filter(cum != max(cum))`

Comment: Exactly, thanks a million! ^^